# setTimeout() not working when inside hasFocus()

Tags: javascript

The code below sends the `30s` event do Google Analytics after 30 seconds a user enters a page.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   gtag('event', '30s');
}, 30000);
```

But when the user minimizes the window, the event still fires.

What I really want is a way to "pause" the `setTimeout` when the user minimizes the page and, when he maximizes the page, the `setTimeout` continues counting from the moment it has stopped.

I tried to put `setTimeout` inside the `hasFocus` statement but it didn't work as expected.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [page visibility API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034) to detect when page focus is lost. When hidden, clear the existing timeout, and set the time remaining into a variable; when shown, set a `setTimeout` with the remaining time. Something along the lines of:

```
let run = false;
const fn = () => {
  gtag('event', '30s');
  run = true;
};
let timeoutId;
let runAt;
let timeLeft = 30_000;
const resume = () => {
  runAt = Date.now() + timeLeft;
  timeoutId = setTimeout(fn, timeLeft);
};
resume();

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  if (document.hidden) {
    timeLeft = runAt - timeLeft;
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  } else if (!run) {
    resume();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.hidden:

```js
setInterval(() => console.log(document.hidden), 1000)
```